# Problem in loading .owl file into Neo4j Desktop

Tags: neo4j, ontology, knowledge-graph, owlready, neosemantics

I am using [python owlready2 library](https://pypi.org/project/Owlready2/) to make and manage .owl file of an ontology I'm working on using python. I want to give the .owl file of my project to [Neo4j Desktop](https://neo4j.com/) and create graph DBMS out of it.
I used this command in Neo4j browser:

```
CALL n10s.onto.import.fetch("file:///D:/codes/Res_TimeLine/TimeLineOnto.owl", "RDF/XML");
```

Although there are many triples made in TimeLineOnto.owl and could be accessed by SPARQL query, no triples are added to Neo4j graph DBMS. using Neosemantics plugin returned same result and no triples added.
At first glance, seems that problem is related to way of addressing in windows or because of .owl format. but using "" instead of "/" in address path of the file and changing file type to .xml do not help either.

I have tried these:

- changing addressing method (based on difference in windows)
- using Neosemantics
- changing file type to .xml

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 0):

The filepath looks slightly off from the [docs](https://neo4j.com/labs/neosemantics/4.1/import/#actual-rdf-import).
[image]

I would go through that page and try the import with their RDF data, using the path conventions and make sure it works before trying your ontology. Also double check that the format in your function call matches your ontology format.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `.owl` file is not in OWL/XML format which is not supported by n10s.
Try to export it in one of the supported serialization formats: RDF/XML, Turtle, JSON-LD, N-Triples...